# When using pd.concat() the resulting dataframe column names appear in parentheses and with an added comma

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm fairly new to Python programming, and I can't figure out why this is happening...  I'm using the "Online Shoppers Purchasing Intention Dataset" from the UCI Machine Learning Repository.
I split the data which has numerical features and categorical features into two separate data frames (one for cat. data and one for num. data), to dummify the categorical variables, and to standardize the numerical variables.  The two dataframes I created are `'StdNumFeat'` for the standardized numericals and `'DumData'` for the dummified categorical variables.

This is an excerpt of `StdNumFeat.head()`

```
   Administrative   Administrative_Duration Informational   Informational_Duration  ProductRelated
0   -0.696993              -0.457191          -0.396478            -0.244931           -0.691003
1   -0.696993              -0.457191          -0.396478            -0.244931           -0.668518
2   -0.696993              -0.457191          -0.396478            -0.244931           -0.691003
3   -0.696993              -0.457191          -0.396478            -0.244931           -0.668518
4   -0.696993              -0.457191          -0.396478            -0.244931           -0.488636
```

And this is an excerpt of `DumData.head()`

```
    Weekend Month_Aug   Month_Dec   Month_Feb   Month_Jul   Month_June  Month_Mar
0    False      0          0            1           0           0           0
1    False      0          0            1           0           0           0
2    False      0          0            1           0           0           0
3    False      0          0            1           0           0           0
4    False      0          0            1           0           0           0
```

When I concatenate the two dataframes using the following code:

`data = pd.concat([StdNumFeat, DumData], axis=1)`

The resulting data frame looks like this:

```
   (Administrative,)    (Administrative_Duration,)  (Informational,)    (Informational_Duration,)
0      -0.696993               -0.457191               -0.396478               -0.244931
1      -0.696993               -0.457191               -0.396478               -0.244931
2      -0.696993               -0.457191               -0.396478               -0.244931
3      -0.696993               -0.457191               -0.396478               -0.244931
4      -0.696993               -0.457191               -0.396478               -0.244931
```

Does anyone know why are the resulting column names followed by a comma, and in parentheses?  What does that mean? Note: I'm using Jupyter Notebooks in Anaconda. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? How is created `StdNumFeat` ?

Comment: You are correct.  I inadvertently used double brackets.  This is the code that I used:

`scaler = StandardScaler()
StdNumFeat = scaler.fit_transform(NumFeat)
StdNumFeat= pd.DataFrame(StdNumFeat)
StdNumFeat.columns = [['Administrative', 'Administrative_Duration', 'Informational',
       'Informational_Duration', 'ProductRelated', 'ExitRates', 'PageValues',
       'SpecialDay']]
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is one level `MultiIndex` in `StdNumFeat`, obviously reason is set columns names by nested list:

```
StdNumFeat.columns = [['Administrative', 'Administrative_Duration', 'Informational',
                      'Informational_Duration', 'ProductRelated']]
```

Correct way:

```
StdNumFeat.columns = ['Administrative', 'Administrative_Duration', 'Informational',
                     'Informational_Duration', 'ProductRelated']
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! Using single brackets as you indicated solved the issue.

Comment: noice it solved my problem as well